# NULL object occurs when implement listener in ListView by using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I'm creating an activity with a list view to show contacts and I'm using a custom adapter which extends SimpleCursorAdapter. The layouts configuration is showed below.

Activity layout file: **activity_load_contacts.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/contacts_list_view" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

List item layout file: **contacts_list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium">
</TextView>
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:id="@+id/load_contact_checkbox"
    android:clickable="false">
</CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
```

Custom adapter class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by admin on 12/08/2016.
 */
public class LoadContactListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public LoadContactListAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {
        TextView contactName = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.load_contact_checkbox);

        if(contactName != null) {
            contactName.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        }
        if(cbx != null) {
            cbx.setId(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));
        }
    }
}
```

**The customer adapter class works fine as it can load contacts to list view.**

Main activity class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoadContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /*
     * Defines an array that contains column names to move from
     * the Cursor to the ListView.
     */
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    /*
     * Defines an array that contains resource ids for the layout views
     * that get the Cursor column contents. The id is pre-defined in
     * the Android framework, so it is prefaced with "android.R.id"
     */
    private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
            android.R.id.text1
    };
    // Define global mutable variables
    // Define a ListView object
    ListView mContactsList;
    // Define variables for the contact the user selects
    // The contact's _ID value
    long mContactId;
    // The contact's LOOKUP_KEY
    String mContactKey;
    // A content URI for the selected contact
    Uri mContactUri;
    // An adapter that binds the result Cursor to the ListView
    private LoadContactListAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private static final String[] PROJECTION =
    {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
                    >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME

    };
    // The column index for the _ID column
    private static final int CONTACT_ID_INDEX = 0;
    // The column index for the LOOKUP_KEY column
    private static final int LOOKUP_KEY_INDEX = 1;

    // Defines the text expression
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private static final String SELECTION =
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?" :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    // Defines a variable for the search string
    public static String mSearchString;
    // Defines the array to hold values that replace the ?
    private String[] mSelectionArgs = { mSearchString };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_contacts);

        // Sets the toolbar as the app bar for the activity
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        // Gets the ListView from the View list of the parent activity
        mContactsList =
                (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);
        // Gets a CursorAdapter
        mCursorAdapter = new LoadContactListAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.contacts_list_item,
                null,
                FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS,
                SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
        // Sets the adapter for the ListView
        mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);

        // Initializes the loader
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        // Set the item click listener to be the current fragment.
        mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("OnContactItemClick: ", "*");
                /*
                 * You can use mContactUri as the content URI for retrieving
                 * the details for a contact.
                 */
                // !!! Here I got a NULL object
                CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.load_contact_checkbox);
                if(cbx != null)
                {
                    boolean isChecked = cbx.isChecked();
                    Log.d("Set checkbox", String.valueOf(isChecked));
                    cbx.setChecked(!isChecked);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("Error: ", view.getClass().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In previous code, when I implement the setOnItemClickListener() function, I try to get the view object of Checkbox. **However, in this situation it will return a null object.** I really don't know why cause the same method works fine in my custom adapter class. Can anyone help me to find what the problem it is?

I am thinking if the view object passed into bindView method and onItemClick method is the same one?
Thanks a lot if anyone can give me some inspiration.